# Failed unmounting /cdrom please remove the installation medium, then press enter

Tags: server

I'm trying to install Ubuntu server on Vmware workstation but after I did all the configuration part it gives me this error (Failed unmounting /cdrom please remove the installation medium, then press enter).

[image]

Note:

1. I only have 2 SSD on my laptop.
2. My laptop does not have a CD place

Update:

I hit enter and the server started but I need to know what I should do.

Comment: What device did you use to install the Ubuntu?

Comment: your laptop devices are irrelevant, because this is a virtual machine. I guess at this point you can probably just remove the CD-ROM (from the VM) and reboot (the VM)

Comment: My device is lenovo

How can I remove the CD-ROM from the VM

Comment: Please clarify you question, you've tagged Lubuntu and Server, but they exist on different ISOs, use different installers and Lubuntu is a desktop system (not a server system).  Please provide OS & release details.

Comment: Ubuntu server 22.04.1 TLS, here is the link https://ubuntu.com/download/server

Comment: Why the Lubuntu tag then, please remove it as Lubuntu uses the `calamares` installer which differs to what you used... details do matter & your question currently is still unclear (it still contradicts itself).  This is a Q&A site & not a forum; comments are from readers to the OP or *original poster*, with replies/fixes/clarifications being (*intended to be*) made to the question itself which allows removal of the comments. Your question still doesn't specify product or release & that is what will be answered.  The faster your question is clear (*without any comments*) you'll attract answers